# Input variable number of values from html-form in sql-table

Tags: php, html, sql, for-loop

I have an html-form with five input fields, where one or more product characteristics can be entered. The entered values should be sent to a SQL-table. This works with a for-loop, when all 5 fields contain values.

```
    <input name="productmaingroupsinput[1]" size="80"/><br>
    <input name="productmaingroupsinput[2]" size="80"/><br>
    <input name="productmaingroupsinput[3]" size="80"/>
    <input name="productmaingroupsinput[4]" size="80"/>
    <input name="productmaingroupsinput[5]" size="80"/>

     $productmaingroupsinput  = $_POST["productmaingroupsinput "];

     for ($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
     $sql="INSERT INTO productmaingroup (productmaingroup_id, product_id, 
     productmaingroups) VALUES ('', (SELECT master_id from producttable 
     WHERE productname='$ productname '), '".productmaingroupsinput 
     [$i]."')";

      mysqli_query($db, $sql);
          }
```

However, when fewer fields are filled with entries, I get empty entries in my SQL-table. Now, I want to avoid empty fields in the SQL-table. I tried it with

```
     if (isset($_POST["productmaingroupsinput[$k]"])) {
                       $j = $k + 1;
             }
```

or

```
    $j = count($productmaingroupsinput);



     for ($i=1; $i<$j; $i++) {
     $sql="INSERT INTO productmaingroup (productmaingroup_id, product_id, 
     productmaingroups) VALUES ('', (SELECT master_id from producttable 
     WHERE productname='$ productname '), '".productmaingroupsinput 
     [$i]."')";
```

but it didn´t work.

How can I make the for-loop dynamic so that it sends only the entered values to the SQL-table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check that if value is null or not..Like if($_POST["productmaingroupsinput"][$i]!=NULL) then only execute that query..I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop the productmaingroupsinput post value and check if empty .do something like this

```
    <?php

    foreach($_POST['productmaingroupsinput'] as $row)
    {

        if($row!='')
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO productmaingroup ( product_id, 
         productmaingroups) VALUES ( (SELECT master_id from producttable 
         WHERE productname='$productname'), '".$row."')";

            mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        }
        else
        {

            echo "value empty";
        }


    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Your condition `if($row!='' && $row!=NULL && !empty($row))` is too weight and wrong. All values from html-forms are transmitted as text. That's why condition `$row!=''` is enough. But condition `!empty($row)` will fail if I submit digit `0` in form.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion @KostyaZhevlakov

Comment: Isn´t there a simple solution, where the dynamic value for $j is found for the for-loop ($i=1; $i<$j; $i++)?

Answer (score 0):

That is my solution:

```
$master = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT master_id from producttable WHERE productname='{$productname}'");
$master_id = $master ? mysqli_fetch_field($master) : 'NULL';
foreach($_POST['productmaingroupsinput'] as $group) {
    if($group=='') {
        continue;
    }
    $groups[] = "('', {$master_id}, '".mysqli_real_escape_string($group)."')";
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO productmaingroup (productmaingroup_id, product_id, productmaingroups) VALUES ".implode(', ', $groups));
```